# Generating the Anonymous public read access to containers and blobs in Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-graph

Using the Azure Resource Graph Explorer
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/BrowseResource/resourceType/Microsoft.Storage%2FStorageAccounts

I need to show an additional column:

```
URI or URL to access
Tags
Size
```

This query does not show those two additional columns I required:

```
resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'
| extend allowBlobPublicAccess = parse_json(properties).allowBlobPublicAccess
| project subscriptionId, resourceGroup, name, allowBlobPublicAccess
```

This PowerShell is also not helping at all: Get-AzStorageAccount

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Hi SSE. Again your determination to treat Stack Overflow as a chatroom, and to create work for volunteer editors, has me perpetually mystified. Why would you draw negative attention to your questions when you want assistance from volunteers?

Comment: Hi @halfer, sure I will take note to be as straightforward as it is above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Size is not appearing in the data that Azure Resource Explorer exposes.

For the rest columns - you can use following query to fetch it:

```
resources
| where type =~ 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts'
| extend props = parse_json(properties)
| extend blobEndpoint = tostring(props.primaryEndpoints.blob), allowBlobPublicAccess=props.allowBlobPublicAccess
| project tags, subscriptionId, resourceGroup, name, blobEndpoint, allowBlobPublicAccess
```

Comment: Hi @alexander, does the result:

 This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. 

mean the BLOB is accessible from the external?